# How to queue two dependent task in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

In my scanning application want to scan and clean the scanned images simultaneouly.I am scanning multiple pages at a time using ADF Scanner.After scanning one page that image want to go for the queue and execute the cleaning process.How to do this in java.

Comment: try producer-consumer pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to execute two operations "simultaneously" you would need to make your application multi-threaded. That is, spawn off a new thread to take care of cleaning of a page after the scanning of that page is complete.

I would suggest taking a look at ExecutorService and it's implementing classes.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html